# How are 'c' or 'r' date format working in PHP?

Tags: php, date, date-formatting, php-7.3

I've tried to format some date using 'c' or 'r' format and I ended up having weird results.

I've tried the PHP interpreter from my personal computer or using the `php:latest` Docker image.

Along the way, I've tried many methods and even the results of these ones surprised me.

```php
var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('c', (new DateTime())->format('c'))); // false
// or
var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('r', (new DateTime())->format('r'))); // false
```

`(new DateTime())->format('c')` returns a string in the expected format but I thought creating a `DateTime` object from it would return a valid object and not `false`.

What's this behavior ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `$t = new DateTime(); echo $t->format('c'); // 012345` this is enough, I think you are complicating things

Comment: I'm trying to check user inputs in my project, not just create an object from the void. That's why I'm using `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to check if the user input match the date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those format characters are unknown as per [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), where it's also stated (emphasis mine):

> `$format` The format that the passed in string should be in. See the formatting options below. In **most cases**, the same letters as for the `date()` can be used.

You can call [`DateTime::getLastErrors()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.getlasterrors.php) to see more (though slightly confusing) details:

```
Array
(
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )

    [error_count] => 2
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => The format separator does not match
            [1] => Trailing data
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you ! I was looking at the wrong documentation >_<
I was reading the `date()` documentation (https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php) :/
Thank you again :D